# Cambiar posicion de un array

Tags: javascript

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con javascript vanilla y quiero cambiar la posicion de un item de un array con otro del mismo array, por ejemplo.

```
['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos']
```

y que Jessica tome la posicion de Luis y Luis pasaria a tomar la posicion de Jessica. asi

```
['Juan', 'Jessica', 'Mario','Luis', 'Marcos']
```

He itentado esto, pero nose como lograr que Luis ocupe la posicion de Jessica

```js
var estudiantes = ['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos'];
estudiantes.splice(1, 1, 'Jessica');
console.log(estudiantes)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes, debes volver aplicar el método [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) sobre el `Array`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var estudiantes = ['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos'];
estudiantes.splice(1, 1, 'Jessica');
estudiantes.splice(3, 1, 'Luis');
console.log(estudiantes)
```

También podrías escribir una función llamada `swap` que reciba los elementos que se intercambiarán, si los mismos existen se intercambian de posición, si no existen se deja el `Array` original.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let swap = (val1, val2, arr) => {
  if(!arr.includes(val1) || !arr.includes(val2)) return;
  let val1_index = arr.indexOf(val1);
  let val2_index = arr.indexOf(val2);
  arr.splice(val1_index, 1, val2);
  arr.splice(val2_index, 1, val1);
}
let estudiantes = ['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos'];
swap('Luis', 'Jessica', estudiantes);
console.log(estudiantes)
```

Answer (score 4):

Si conoces los índices, puedes cambiar los elementos reindexando el array

```js
const arr = ['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos'];
arr[1] = "Jessica";
arr[3] = "Luis";
console.log(arr);

// ['Juan', 'Jessica', 'Mario','Luis', 'Marcos']
```

Ahora bien, si no se saben los índices, puedes usar [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) para obtener el índice de algún elemento

> El método `indexOf()` retorna el primer índice en el que se puede encontrar un elemento dado en el array, ó retorna -1 si el elemento no esta presente.

```js
const arr = ['Juan', 'Luis', 'Mario','Jessica', 'Marcos'];
function revertItems(a, s, r) {
  // Donde s es el valor a buscar
  // Y r es el valor a encontrar y revertir con el otro
  const sindex = a.indexOf(s);
  const rindex = a.indexOf(r);
  // Encontrar los índices de cada uno
  if (sindex === -1 || rindex === -1) return "No encontrado!";
  // Si alguno de los elementos no existe dentro del array, se detiene la ejecución de la función
  a[sindex] = r;
  a[rindex] = s;
  // Revertir los valores
  return a;
}
console.log(revertItems(arr, "Luis", "Jessica"));
// ['Juan', 'Jessica', 'Mario','Luis', 'Marcos']
```